# How to update UI real-time and continuously?

Tags: android, performance, feed

I need to show feeds in my app and want to update UI real-time same like Twitter app?

As per my understandings, Below are the few ways,

1. I can do this by continuous background call to API from service and update UI using handlers.
2. I can register broadcast receiver and fire them once updated data is available and then update UI if the user is still on the same page.

However, I need to find the best way except this if possible because in future it can increase traffic of users/feeds.

Comment: there is no "best way". *You* decide what works best in your scenario

Comment: Ok Thanks. But out of above 2 which once is highly recommended or apps like Twitter use?

Comment: For updating the UI continuously, either you may get notification when there is updated data on server and based on that you can update the model and Views boths ' and/or ' you may call background service on constant period and check for the data availability.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) I can do this by continuous background call to API from service and
>   update UI using handlers.

Don't use this method, continuous background call of an API will reduce the performance.

> 2) I can register broadcast receiver and fire them once updated data is available and then update UI if the user is still on the same page.

When to send the broadcast?
For this, you can get push notification from backend which tells your app that updated data is available and you can continue with your **BroadcastReceiver**

Overall **2nd** will be the option instead of 1st.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging api to get the notification that your database has changed. In this case, the notification will be of type 'data'. Once you get the notification from FCM, you need to handle your logic in `onMessageReceived()` method. From there you can use `EventBus` or `BroadcastReceiver` whichever suits your requirements.